# How to give the information about request.user to clean method

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

I have a form:

```
class CreateConferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Conference
        fields = ['name', 'participants']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CreateConferenceForm, self).clean()
        if not request.user.id in cleaned_data.get('participants'):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Error')
```

But I don't know how to import a request object from view, because method is_valid hasn't additional arguments. How I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your form an `__init__` method that allows you to pass a user:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now you can use `self.user` in clean. Wherever you create the form remember to pass the user, e.g. `form = CreateConferenceForm(request.user, request.POST)` in the view.

Comment: `self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)` will not break existing code. Of course it would require checking for `self.user` in clean.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: I feel existing code _should_ break if it's not updated.